# Couchbase continuous replication limitation

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm using Couchbase Lite in a mobile app. Just wondering:

1. is there any limitation if I create continuous replication to sync data between mobile device and server?
2. How many concurrent continuous replication can be handled by one couchDB or coubchbase server?
3. If reach the limit, what will happen on mobile side and server side?

Thanks! Frank

Comment: This is something that cannot be answered definitively.  It depends on a large number of factors such as hardware and network performance.  However, there was a pretty big discussion on things relating to this on our forums:  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cblite-size-bandwidth-and-replication-considerations-for-1m-docs-100-000-of-them-updated-every-10-sec/5622/33